# Using continue/break inside boolean statement [V8]

Tags: javascript, v8

if

```
true && (function () { console.log('executed'); })()
```

is ok, then why

```
true && continue;
```

or

```
true && (continue);
```

doesn't work, e.g. V8 (Node) throws:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token continue
```

Comment: What would ever be a use for this?  Continue is used to break out of a loop/conditional early.  It is not a boolean value

Comment: [here](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/general-patterns/conditionals.html) see line 125

Comment: That example is completely different than using `continue`. While it is still a statement and cannot be used as explained below, using continue inside a boolean statement would never be done, just trying to figure out why you used that as an example instead of using `true && result++` which was your real example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, there are expressions and statements. Statements can contain expressions, but not the other way round. The statement `true && false;` is an expression statement.

[`&&`](http://es5.github.com/#x11.11) expects two expressions.

Both [`true`](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.2) and [`(function() { ... })()`](http://es5.github.com/#x13) are *expressions* - a boolean expression evaluating to `true`, and a function expression (wrapped inside parentheses and then called) evaluating to `undefined`.

[`continue`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.7) is a *statement*, so you cannot use `&&`. You'll have to use [`if`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.5) because `if` does accept a statement to be run when the condition is true.

It's correct behaviour according to the specification and should not be V8-specific.

Comment: @jakubmal: What do you mean? `if(true) continue;` works, and isn't much more code.

Comment: meh, I know, that's for fun, still, `true && (continue, 1)` doesn't work

Comment: @jakubmal: No, because you still have an `continue` statement inside an expression. A statement is by definition "standalone", it cannot appear within parentheses or as operands.

Answer (score 0):

Because `continue` isn't expression that return some value. And full boolean expression as well as its parts must return some value.